# Is there a way in Android to detect that my App is getting uninstalled?

Tags: android, uninstallation

I want to trigger the logout process for the user in case the user uninstalls my app.
This way I want to ensure that I reach the user via other means like SMS / email instead of sending app Notification.

Is it possible to run some code just before uninstallation of my Android App ?

Comment: Generally, no, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible to run some code just before uninstallation of my Android App?**

No. You can get the broadcast for any other package getting uninstalled but never for your own package.

But you can observe other packages being removed by registering for this event.

```
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
```